# Breeze.js with WCF Data Service

Tags: single-page-application, breeze

I just started exploring the js library, breeze.js. I've looked through the samples but can't seem to find any example on how to consume a WCF Data Service (all the examples seem to be on Web API).

Does any one know how to consume a WCF Data Service (or any other OData service) with breeze.js?

I read somewhere in the docs that breeze.js only supports reads for OData services at the moment. That is fine by me as the use-case I'm considering it for does not include writes to the OData Service.

Comment: @Will, Pls. why was this question closed?

Comment: Is the question still valid, or is the answer jaydata?

Comment: The appropriate answer is Jay's below and I've accepted it as such. Jaydata is a very good alternative I stumbled upon.

Comment: You're right Will, I never should have pitched Jaydata as the answer. I guess I was looking at it from the perspective of what solved the problem for me at that time rather than the correct perspective of 'What is the answer to this question I have asked?'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The configuration described in this answer is no longer correct!

I am one of the engineers on Breeze.

The simplest way to talk to an OData service with Breeze is to first configure breeze to talk to OData.

```
breeze.core.config.setProperties({
    // the OData provider
    remoteAccessImplementation: entityModel.remoteAccess_odata;
    // this is the Knockout provider but we also provide a Backbone provider
    //  and we have others on the way
    trackingImplementation: entityModel.entityTracking_ko,
});
```

and then initialize an EntityManager and make your first query.

```
var myServiceName = "http://localhost:9009/ODataService.svc";
var em = new breeze.entityModel.EntityManager( {serviceName: myServiceName });

var query = breeze.entityModel.EntityQuery.from("Customers")
    .where("CompanyName", "startsWith", "B")
    .orderBy("City");

em.executeQuery(query).then(function(data) {
   // process the results here.
});
```

You should be able to consume any OData service in this manner.

The Breeze docs at http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/introduction can provide a great deal more information.

Also, please let us know what it was that made you feel that JayData was a better fit. This is how we improve our product.

thanks

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for your response. I assumed Jaydata was a better fit because the documentation was replete with examples on how to consume an OData service.

Comment: does breeze work with WDS 5.2 and it's new JSON serialization format?

Comment: I also see that setProperties is now deprecated. What is the recommended way to set this up?

Comment: breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance or breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances. For example:

 breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({       
        dataService: "oData"
    });

Answer (score 0):

## Corrected OData configuration and example

Jay's answer appears to be substantially out of date. I do not believe that any trace remains in Breeze of the `entityModel` type that appears in that answer. The following snippet from that answer **will fail**:

```
entityModel.remoteAccess_odata // does not work!
```

### Do This!

As I write, the recommended way to configure Breeze so that it talks to a standard OData source (such as a WCF OData service) is

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'OData', true);
```

The balance of Jay's answer needs a slight correction to remove the reference to `entityModel`:

```
// specify the absolute URL to the WCF service address
var serviceName = "http://localhost:9009/ODataService.svc";

var em = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName );

var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Customers")
    .where("CompanyName", "startsWith", "B")
    .orderBy("City");

em.executeQuery(query).then(function(data) {
   // process the data.results here.
});
```